# Non positive-definiteness of some binomial matrices

Tags: symmetric-matrices

Experience shows that the following matrix
$$
A_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which could be called a binomial matrix, or a Pascal matrix, is not positive definite, along the like matrices $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$. Is this a theorem valid for all $n$?

Same question for
$$
B_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
1   & c_1  & c_2  & c_3  & c_4\\
c_1 & 2c_2 & 3c_3 & 4c_4 & 0 \\
c_2 & 3c_3 & 6c_4 & 0    & 0 \\
c_3 & 4c_4 & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
c_4 & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and like matrices, where the $c_i$'s are arbitrary reals.

Comment: Have you tried to show that $0$ is an eigenvalue for both $A_n$ and $B_n$? (except from $n=1$ I guess)

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Opsss, you are right! I'm sorry

Comment: A real symmetric matrix with a 0 on the diagonal can't be positive definite; if its determinant is nonzero, it can't be positive semidefinite either.

Answer (score 0):

the original question, used in [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).  The displayed matrix products fit with the usual method of repeated "completing the square".  In the $n$ by $n$ case, about half the coefficients may be taken to be $1,$  the rest negative.

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 &  - 7 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 59 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 59 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 96 }{ 59 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 7 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 59 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 4 &  - 9 &  -  \frac{ 14 }{ 19 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 19 }  &  -  \frac{ 107 }{ 833 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 19 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1666 }{ 19 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1250 }{ 833 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 &  - 9 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 14 }{ 19 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 19 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 107 }{ 833 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 4 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$